# Variable alignment component in string interpolation

Tags: c#, string, string-interpolation

The [alignment component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#alignment-component) is the `-20` in this example:

`$"{value, -20}"`

Is there a way to make an interpolated string like this:

`$"{value, alignment}"`

where `alignment` is a variable?

Comment: string interpolation is just dressed up/hidden `String.Format`. If you can't do something via `Format`, you cannot do it via string interpolation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `alignment` cannot be a variable. The `alignment` has to be a constant expression. Here is the relevant section from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#structure-of-an-interpolated-string)

> **alignment:**    The constant expression whose value defines the minimum number of characters in the string representation of the result of the interpolated expression. If positive, the string representation is right-aligned; if negative, it's left-aligned. For more information, see [Alignment Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#alignment-component).

Comment: This seems weird. If result string can be composed from dynamic variables, why they need constant expression for alignment? The output need to be evaluated at runtime anyway, right?

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned alignment must be constant, but could try using Padleft in a similar fashion (not sure if that would work for you or not).

That or would have to have various string interpolations for 1 string.

```
string test;

if (value.length > 100)
     test = "${value: -20}";
else test = "${value : 20}";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Why not pad left?

```
    var p = Math.Max(Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length), c.Length);

    Console.WriteLine(a.PadLeft(p));
    Console.WriteLine(b.PadLeft(p) + " +");
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', p));
    Console.WriteLine(c.PadLeft(p));
```

It's dynamic and (in my use case) adaptive:

[image]